# Laravel 8 Validator Fails with Nested JSON Request on POST API

Tags: php, json, laravel, nested, laravel-8

I have a POST API function in Laravel 8 in which I receive data and process it accordingly. The function first Validates the required data and then proceeds accordingly. As long as the JSON passed is plain JSON all works fine. Validator validates well. Data is inserted into database properly too. But when I make it nested JSON it stops working.

```
public function createExpense(Request $req){
  $loggedIn = Auth::user()->id; // GET USER ID OF CURRENT LOGGED IN USER

  // VALIDATE POST DATA
  $validator = Validator::make($req->all(), [
    'primaryExpenseAmount' => 'required',
    'expenseName' => 'required'
  ]);

  // CHECK VALIDATION AND PROCEED ACCORDINGLY
  if($validator->fails()){
    // VALIDATION FAILED
    $response = ['message' => $validator->errors()->first()]; // RETURN FAILED VALIDATION MESSAGE
  }else{
    // VALIDATION SUCCESSFUL
  }
}
```

Working JSON

```
{
    "userId":1,
    "expenseType": "Multi",
    "primaryExpenseAmount": 155,
    "secondaryExpenseAmount": 10,
    "secondaryExpenseCurrencyId": 2,
    "expenseName": "GYM Nutrition",
    "merchantId": 1,
    "locationId": "",
    "locationName": "Shastri Nagar",
    "locationLatitude": "22.3854738",
    "locationLongitude": "28.757372",
    "expenseDate": "2021-03-24",
    "paymentMode": 1
}
```

Stops working when made Nested. Validator fails and sends response `primaryExpenseAmount is required`.

```
{
    "userId":1,
    "expenseType": "Multi",
    "primaryExpenseAmount": 155,
    "secondaryExpenseAmount": 10,
    "secondaryExpenseCurrencyId": 2,
    "expenseName": "GYM Nutrition",
    "merchantId": 1,
    "locationId": "",
    "locationName": "Shastri Nagar",
    "locationLatitude": "22.3854738",
    "locationLongitude": "28.757372",
    "expenseDate": "2021-03-24",
    "paymentMode": 1,
    "tags":[
      {
         "tagId":1,
         "amount":"100",
         "currencyId":"",
         "isCustom":"true/false"
      },
      {
         "tagId":2,
         "amount":"100",
         "currencyId":"",
         "isCustom":"true/false"
      },
      {
         "tagId":3,
         "amount":"100",
         "currencyId":"",
         "isCustom":"true/false"
      }
   ]
}
```

Can somebody please throw a light on what mistake I am making here?

Comment: Can you show what you get with`dd($req->all());` before validation in non-working situation?

Comment: I use postman... and I am new to Laravel as well.. Where should I run that command? In browser or postman is fine?

Comment: After `$loggedIn = Auth::user()->id;` put `dd($req->all());` and you will see what you have in your request. You can do it in postman too.

Comment: @mare96 In postman it's returning <script> values

Comment: It should return something like [this](https://imgur.com/8exX8TD). Check the preview tab.

Comment: @mare96 It's not returning that.. I am just getting `[]`. That's all in the preview tab. But yes, I do get that when I remove the tags part which is nested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231082/discussion-between-mare96-and-shreyansh-kashyap).